# Spring security implementation with AWS congnito authentication on front end

Tags: spring-security, amazon-cognito

I separate my application into 2 parts:

- Front end : Vue js and connected with AWS congnito for login feature (email/pw or google social login).
- Back end : Spring boot Restful. User information stored in database (a unique id from congnito as primary key.)

My flow of authentication

1. User redirected to congnito and login. congnito will return a unique id and JWT.
2. Front end passes the unique id and JWT to back end controller.
3. backend validate JWT and return user information from DB

My question is:

- Is this a bad practice to authenticate on front end and pass data to back end for spring security? If so, may I have any suggestion to change my implementation flow?
- To call AuthenticationProvider.authenticate, a Authentication consist username (in my case, the unique id from cognito) and password is needed (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken). Are there any implementation to set only username? or it is fine to set password as empty string?

```
// controller
public String login(HttpServletRequest req, String cognitoId, String jwt) { 
    // check JWT with AWS
    if(!AwsJwtChecker(cognitoId, jwt))
        return createErrorResponseJson("invalid jwt");

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq
      = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(cognitoId, "");
    Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(authReq);

    SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    sc.setAuthentication(auth);
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, sc);

    MyUser user = userRepository.selectUserByCognitoId(cognitoId);
    return createLoginSuccessResponse(user);
}

// web config
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
      String cognitoId = authentication.getName();

      // check user exist in db or not
      MyUser user = userRepository.selectUserByCognitoId(cognitoId);
      if (user != null) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, "", user.getRoles());
       } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed");
       }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?>aClass) {
        return aClass.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a bad practice to authenticate on front end and pass data to back end for spring security? If so, may I have any suggestion to change my implementation flow?

No, in fact it's best practice. JWT is exactly for that purpose: You can store information about the user and because of the signature of the token, you can be certain, that the information is trustworthy.

You don't describe what you are saving in the database, but from my perspective, you are mixing two authentication methods. While it's not forbidden, it might be unnecessary. Have you analysed your token with [jwt.io](https://www.jwt.io)? There are many information about the user within the token and more can be added.

Cognito is limited in some ways, like number of groups, but for a basic application it might be enough. It has a great API to manage users from within your application, like adding groups or settings properties.

You don't describe what you do with the information that is returned with 3). Vue can too use the information stored in the jwt to display a username or something like that. You can decode the token with the [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) library, eg, and get an object with all information.

> To call AuthenticationProvider.authenticate...

Having said that, my answer to your second question is: You don't need the whole authentication part in you `login` method.

```
// controller
public String login(HttpServletRequest req, String cognitoId, String jwt) { 
    // check JWT with AWS
    if(!AwsJwtChecker(cognitoId, jwt))
        return createErrorResponseJson("invalid jwt");

    return userRepository.selectUserByCognitoId(cognitoId);
}
```

This should be completely enough, since you already validate the token. No need to authenticate the user again. When spring security is set up correctly, the jwt will be set in the SecurityContext automatically.

The problem I see with your implementation is that anyone could send a valid jwt and a random cognitoId and receive user information from the database. So it would be better to parse the jwt and use something from within the jwt, like username, as identifier in the database. The token can't be manipulated, otherwise the validation fails.

```
public String login(String jwt) { 
    // check JWT with AWS
    if(!AwsJwtChecker(jwt))
        return createErrorResponseJson("invalid jwt");

    String identifier = getIdentifier(jwt);

    return userRepository.selectUserByIdentifier(identifier);
}
```

Comment: Thanks theshadog, you answer gave me an idea how should I update my implementation. As you mentioned, cognito have limitation, from what i understand from it,it just allow to store some basic information of the users, such as date of birth, name, or roles etc. If my application want to customize my pages based on user information, cognito may not enough for me. So I choose to integrate with my own database.

Comment: May you also let me know more about "When spring security is set up correctly, the jwt will be set in the SecurityContext automatically." ? The reason why i want to use spring security is, I want to block for example, a normal using calling the admin API by using @Roles. Although Cognito also allow me to set group or roles of users, but checking in front end is not save, and getting a new JWT every time may also not be a good idea as it reduce performance.

Comment: Here I described how to set up spring security 5 with her: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59962580/10020419 do you need more information?

Comment: The main difference is that you send the token with every request in your ```Authorization ``` header. It is saved in your frontend application state and you can get it by JavaScript from your localStorage.get(“access_token“) (or was it “id_token“)? With this you don't need to get a new token every time, it is stored there as long as it is valid.

Comment: Sorry I have one more question. Based on the answer in your another post, how do it check is the jwt expired? Do the spring security check the Authorization header automatically for every http request?

Comment: Inside the payload is a parameter ```exp``` telling you in milliseconds when the token will expire. Spring checks the expiration automatically.  And yes, spring checks the header every time a request is received.

Comment: Your Frontend should check the expiration as well and refresh the token if it has expired using the ``refresh_token```. By that the user doesn't have to log in again to verify after token expiration.